# kendo ui scheduler recurrence rule set

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I try to do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    var newdata = {
    id: tests[i].ID,
    start: new Date(tests[i].From),
    end: new Date(tests[i].To),
    isAllDay: false,
    title: tests[i].Name,
    SelectedMode: tests[i].FK_tMode,
    recurrenceException: new Date("2050/9/3 12:00").toISOString(),
    recurrenceId: null,
    recurrenceRule: "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE,TH,FR"
}
$("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.add(newdata)
```

And I get an recurrenceException: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'recurrenceException' of undefined.
Can somebody tell me what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you post up your `kendoScheduler` definition? According to [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/recurrence-series-bug#jiTMm9NovE-Te_zJPPlmMQ), recurrence errors are caused _"when the defined events do not have specified ids"_. Additionally, you are not assigning a list of objects to the scheduler datasource with the above code, you are overwriting `newdata` on each iteration of your for loop. Try instantiating `newdata` before the loop and use `push` to add new objects (if this is the desired functionality)

Comment: Did you define a schema for the scheduler DataSource?

Comment: '$("#testmodescheduler").kendoScheduler({                   
                    resources: [{
                        field: "SelectedMode",
                        title: "Mode",
                        dataSource: ko.mapping.toJS(self.Modes()),
                        dataTextField: "Name",
                        dataValueField: "ID"
                        }
                   
                    ],
                    dataSource: []                    
                }
                });'

Comment: Without the recurence all is working without problem. Only with the recurence i have problem